# Remove duplicates

Tags: python, django

I try to generate email distribution lists from contacts. On my page I use checkboxes for every list. In my Django view I have:

```
context['distribution_list'] = []
for entry in request.GET:
    context['distribution_list'].extend(list(Contact.objects.all().filter(lists__name__exact=entry)))
```

This seems to work, but I still have duplicate entries. What would be the best way to remove the duplicates?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If order does not matter it's just a `context['distribution_list'] = list(set(context['distribution_list']))` after the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure how `for entry in request.GET:` is working.

However, you can use the [`distinct()` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

```
entries = [entry for entry in request.GET]
Contact.objects.filter(lists__name__in=entries).distinct()
```

Comment: Via `for entry in request.GET` I get the names of all activated checkboxes, hence distribution lists I want to query. Then I have to do a query for each list and extend "distribution_list". If a contact is on more than one of the lists, the contact is in the list more than once. These are the duplicates I'd like to remove.

Comment: Use the `distinct()` clause like I have mentioned in the answer

Comment: But doesn't this only make sure that the results of each single query do not have any duplicates? The Problem exists because I extend 'distribution_list' with results from the other queries which may contain an entry that does already exist in 'distribution_list'.